# Android: How to show all the items of listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have list view, with a list view as one of its items. The inner list view have 2 to 4 items, so I don't want to make it scrollable but just show all the items. Right now I am using `WRAP_CONTENT` size for that listView but it only shows the first item and does not shows the rest of them.

I know that instead list view I can use Linear layout. But it just easier for me to work with list view, and not handling the items updates by my self.

Also I can't set a fixed hight for the inner list view since the number of elements it's not constant.

Any ideas, how can I make the list view to be at the size of all the children?

Comment: you should not use listview inside an another listview.

Comment: `I have list view, with a list view as one of its items.` Why not an `ExpandableListView`, then?

Comment: @DerGolem because the main list view may have over 100 items

Comment: The Android folks discourage the use of scrollable views within scrollable view.  Which view owns the user's touch events? It's very problematic for the developer. Very clunky for the user

Comment: @Martin It's not the case here, as I am using the inner listview just to present the data, not to interact with the view. I will how ever update the data for the inner view, and there for I prefer using listView over linear layout.